How to implement robust reconnect mechanism for Redis in Nest.js microservices
I'm trying to make a robust reconnect mechanism for redis in Nest.js microservices.
How do I test reconnect:
I bootstrap microservice(as hybrid application in my case). With working Redis in docker compose.
After that I turn Redis off. Check my my microservice will work with that and after some time I turn Redis on.
Current behaviour:
Microservice make retry attempts only provided times. After that my microservice will not try to connect to the Redis, even if Redis is available.
What I want to implement:
I want to make retries till the moment when microservice connect to the Redis. That's why I try to use retryStrategy and reconnectOnError. But none of them will work in case of unavailable Redis service.
Dependencies:
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.4.3",
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.3.2",

Here is code of Nest.js microservice.
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { RedisOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './common/filters';
import {
  MICROSERVICE_APP_PORT,
  REDIS_HOST,
  REDIS_PORT,
} from './config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.connectMicroservice<RedisOptions>({
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      host: REDIS_HOST,
      port: REDIS_PORT,
      retryAttempts: 3,
      retryDelay: 100,
      connectionName: 'MY_MICROSERVICE',
      keepAlive: 1000,
      autoResubscribe: true,
      retryStrategy: (times: number) => {
        console.log('retryStrategy ');
        const delay = Math.min(times * 100, 3000);
        return delay;
      },
      reconnectOnError: (err) => {
        console.log('reconnectOnError');
        console.log('err ', err);
        return true;
      },
    },
  });

  app.useLogger(new Logger());

  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());

  await app.startAllMicroservices();

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
    console.error(' ~ process.unhandledRejection ~ :', reason);
    app.get(Logger).debug(reason);
  });

  process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error(' ~ process.uncaughtException ~ :', err);
    app.get(Logger).debug(err);
  });

  app.listen(MICROSERVICE_APP_PORT);
}

bootstrap(); 

I also try to add username and password to the Redis in order to simulate Redis error. In this case I will have error data in reconnectOnError, but if I return true it will not make retry attempts more than provided value.
